# Show tabs from last time in non-default Multifox profile

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, identity-management

I am using [Multifox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multifox/), a Firefox add-on to use different identities (websites login) in different windows.

I have the general Firefox option `Show my windows and tabs from last time` option enabled.
Multifox does not seem to have its own preferences dialog.

When I start Firefox, the tabs from last time are correctly loaded.
**BUT PROBLEM:** then when I open a new window as a separate identity, it is shown with only `about:startpage`, whatever tabs I had open last time are lost.

**QUESTION:** How can I get my tabs from last time in non-default Multifox identities too?

I tried closing the windows in different orders. It seems like the tabs of the last window to be closed (default or not) overwrite the tabs of the default session next time Firefox is started. Subsequently opened profiles windows have `about:startpage` only, whatever the profile.

Comment: Wouldn't not closing the window before exiting FF restore it along with the main one?

Comment: @KardNails: I just tried and added my findings, which are quite unfortunate.

Comment: What happens if you exit via File > Exit/Quit without closing any of the open windows or tabs? What about when killing the FF process?